# getting error in terraform while creating instances aand subnets

Tags: indexing, count, terraform, subnet, cidr

My instance subnets code creation is below:

```
resource "aws_vpc" "default" {
    cidr_block = "${var.vpc_cidr}"
    enable_dns_hostnames = true
    tags = {
        Name = "${var.vpc_name}"
    }
}

resource "aws_internet_gateway" "default" {
    vpc_id = "${aws_vpc.default.id}"
    tags = {
        Name = "${var.IGW_name}"
    }
}

resource "aws_subnet" "subnets" {
    count = 3 
    vpc_id = "${aws_vpc.default.id}"
    cidr_block = "${element(var.cidrs, count.index)}"
    availability_zone = "${element(var.azs, count.index)}"

    tags = {
        Name = "Public-Subnet-${count.index+1}"
    }
}
```

My code output is showing error in function call i.e., below

```
Error: Error in function call

  on main.tf line 26, in resource "aws_subnet" "subnets":
  26:     cidr_block = "${element(var.cidrs, count.index)}"
    |----------------
    | count.index is 2
    | var.cidrs is empty list of string

Call to function "element" failed: cannot use element function with an empty
list.


Error: Error in function call

  on main.tf line 26, in resource "aws_subnet" "subnets":
  26:     cidr_block = "${element(var.cidrs, count.index)}"
    |----------------
    | count.index is 1
    | var.cidrs is empty list of string

Call to function "element" failed: cannot use element function with an empty
list.


Error: Error in function call

  on main.tf line 26, in resource "aws_subnet" "subnets":
  26:     cidr_block = "${element(var.cidrs, count.index)}"
    |----------------
    | count.index is 0
    | var.cidrs is empty list of string

Call to function "element" failed: cannot use element function with an empty
list.
```

i'm running terraform below command:

```
terraform plan --var-filr tf.vars
```

curious to know why it is reporting these errors and how to solve it.
i think it is taking subnets first not instance .

Answer (score 0):

```
var.cidrs is empty list of string
```

It says the cidrs variable is empty.